# Bootstrap 4 carousel-fade animation not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I was working on my web project where I used form over carousel using css. It's working perfectly with sliding animation but when I am adding class `carousel-fade` the form at the center is also fading with the carousel but I want to prevent that. Here, In example instead of that big form I used a simple `<div>` tag for demonstration. How can I solve this issue ?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"> 
</script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
  $(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 1000
  }) ;
  }) ;
  </script>
  
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <style>
  /*CSS*/
#vcenter {
   position: absolute ;
   top: 55%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   font-weight: bold ;
}

div#back1{
   background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/11744/pexels-photo-11744.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
   height: 100vh ;
   background-attachment: scroll;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div#back2{
   background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/207130/pexels-photo-207130.jpeg?    auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
   height: 100vh ;
   background-attachment: scroll;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div#back3{
   background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1178683/pexels-photo-1178683.jpeg?    auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
   height: 100vh ;
   background-attachment: scroll;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
  
</style>


<body>

<!-- carousel -->
<div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div id="back1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div id="back2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div id="back3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="vcenter" class="container">
  <p class="text-center text-primary">I am at center</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: @ManirajMurugan thanks for the help, spent so much time to solve this problem

Comment: Yes mate, Sometimes we usually stuck somewhere like this.. This is all our coding world.. Glad to help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `z-index: 1;` css property to `#vcenter` ..

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"> 
</script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
  $(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 1000
  }) ;
  }) ;
  </script>
  
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <style>
  /*CSS*/
#vcenter {
   position: absolute ;
   top: 55%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   font-weight: bold ;
   z-index: 1;
}

div#back1{
   background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/11744/pexels-photo-11744.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
   height: 100vh ;
   background-attachment: scroll;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div#back2{
   background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/207130/pexels-photo-207130.jpeg?    auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
   height: 100vh ;
   background-attachment: scroll;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div#back3{
   background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1178683/pexels-photo-1178683.jpeg?    auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
   height: 100vh ;
   background-attachment: scroll;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
  
</style>


<body>

<!-- carousel -->
<div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div id="back1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div id="back2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div id="back3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="vcenter" class="container">
  <p class="text-center text-primary">I am at center</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this class 'carousel-fade' from first div and if you want to add any extra class then used your own class name instead of default carousel class name.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `z-index` higher then 1 to `#vcenter`:

```
#vcenter {
   position: absolute ;
   top: 55%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   font-weight: bold ;
   z-index: 9;
}
```

You need that because the active slide has a `z-index` of `1`. Check that yourself. :)